# Capture cell value on worksheet when user right clicks a tab and deletes?

Tags: excel, vba

Been searching but cannot find any reference to what I am trying to accomplish.

**Background**
I use a worksheet (worksheer#2) to enter certain data for an aircraft model. When the data is correct I run a macro to copy that data into another worksheet and rename the cipued one with the aircraft name. I do this for as many aircraft as i need. All created sheets are all placed between two other blank sheets named Start and End.

I can manipulate any specific worksheet by name using buttons on worksheet #2 perfectly and when the macro runs it updates relevant cells on worksheet#2 accordingly.

Those values are required elsewhere in my workbook and have to be correct. That all works fine but it all falls over when the worksheet is deleted/moved by way of right clicking the worksheet tab and then deleteing or holding and dragging the sheet to another location.

Is there a way to capture the worksheet name when it is manipulated in this fashion so I can use the info to update data on worksheet #2 with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a worksheet-level event called **`BeforeDelete`**.

- Right click on the tab and choose `View Code`
- In the `General` drop-down at the top-left of the VBA Editor, choose ``WorkSheet" and in the `(Declarations)` drop down at top-right, choose `BeforeDelete`.

This will create an empty procedure where you can add your code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

[image: img]

---

### More Information:

- [**Worksheet.BeforeDelete Event** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-beforedelete-event-excel)

Comment: duh!.. :) Thanks for this Asheeldawg.. Appreciate you taking time to post.

Comment: You're welcome and don't sweat it - for me, it's always the *simplest* tasks that end up taking me to most time! (Don't forget to 'accept' an answer that helps you solve your problem with the checkmark to left left of the answer)